# Redirect Users Clicking on a link in your site that goes to an offsite URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, social-networking

We are changing our social account names/urls.  I'll have to go through our websites, emails, etc... and manually change hundred+ number of links. I think our CMS might have the ability to do most of the work on the web, but let's assume it won't for fun.

Since social sites live outside of our domain (facebook, twitter, etc...). I was toying with the idea of replacing the old urls with the new url with jquery or Js. Such as:

```
 $("a[href^='http://OldSocialLink1.com']")
 .each(function()
{ 
  this.href = this.href.replace(/^http:\/\/newSocialLink1\.com, 
      "http://OldSocialLink1.com");
});
```

Is there a better way to do this-besides changing all the links manually? Possible onclick - If you are on one of our pages and you come across an old social link to facebook and clicked it.  Change oldFBLink to new link.

Answer (score 0):

I know of a good search & replace utility available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/daelan/WordPress-Migration-Script/blob/master/migrate.php).  All you need to do is save it and transfer it to the root directory of your site and navigate to it at 'yoursite.com/migrate.php'

Say if you wanted to change facebook links from 'facebook.com/oldurl' to 'facebook.com/newurl', simply input the new and old URL into the script page.  I know this script has been very useful to me while migrating WordPress sites which requires old URLs to be replaced with new ones.  Hopefully this script can help you as much as it helped me!